# Python understanding method for hashing class

Tags: python, class, oop

This was meant to be the second part of my previous question but I decided to ask them as separate questions. I'm following the following code implementing a hashtable from the MIT lecture notes/videos. The lecturer does not explain his code so I can't get the answer to the questions from the video. I'm new to OOP and i would like to fully understand this particular method. Here is the [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ud27N.png) that is implemented:

```
class intSet(object):
    #An intSet is a set of integers
    def __init__(self):
        """Create an empty set of integers"""
        self.numBuckets = 47
        self.vals = []
        for i in range(self.numBuckets):
            self.vals.append([])

    def hashE(self, e):
        #Private function, should not be used outside of class
        return abs(e)%len(self.vals)

    def insert(self, e):
        """Assumes e is an integer and inserts e into self"""
        for i in self.vals[self.hashE(e)]:
            if i == e: return
        self.vals[self.hashE(e)].append(e)

    def member(self, e):
        """Assumes e is an integer
           Returns True if e is in self, and False otherwise"""
        return e in self.vals[self.hashE(e)]

    def __str__(self):
        """Returns a string representation of self"""
        elems = []
        for bucket in self.vals:
            for e in bucket: elems.append(e)
        elems.sort()
        result = ''
        for e in elems: result = result + str(e) + ','
        return '{' + result[:-1] + '}'
```

I do not understand why the method `insert(self,e)` works. Here is my understanding. 
The value `e` is only appended if the return statement is executed, and this depends on the if statement `if i==e`. I believe, since initially `self.vals` is just a list of empty lists this if statement will never be true and thus nothing will be returned. However in the video lecturer the code works fine. Why is this the case?

Am I reading the code wrong with the indentations? I am new to Python so is it the case that perhaps `if i==e` is true the method returns nothing, otherwise it skips to the last line and appends the value, thus ensuring an element is not added twice? I appreciate any help, thanks!!

Comment: Please consider writing your code instead of embedding it as a picture. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "[I]s it the case that perhaps if i==e is true the method returns
>   nothing, otherwise it skips to the last line and appends the value,
>   thus ensuring an element is not added twice?"

Yes, this is what happens. You figured it out! Good job. You said you're new, so a suggestion for the future is to start up Python in interactive mode, which you can do by just running `python` in your command line. In there you can test simple code (such as this insert function) and see its behavior, which might help you understand what's going on in a function all by yourself.

Here is [a tutorial I found](http://www.python-course.eu/interactive.php) on interactive mode if you're interested.

`if i==e: return` is a conditional, but it only takes up one line, in which case an indent is not required.